# How did Spielberg come to direct Ready Player One?

Tags: steven-spielberg, ready-player-one

It was relatively recently announced that Steven Spielberg will be directing the movie Ready Player One, based off of the book by the same name.  Looking through his history of films he has directed, this story stands out as radically different, at least to me, compared to anything else he has done.

How has it come to be that Steven Spielberg is directing this movie?

Comment: I'm not perfectly acquainted with all the intricacies of that book's story, but to me it seems he's directed so many different things that it's hard to say in which way this is really *"radically different"* from anything he's done before. I'd never attributed that much of a specific genre or kind of movie to Spielberg. Interesting question, but could you maybe elaborate a little?

Comment: Someone probably has to ask this question to Steven Spielberg.

Comment: @DA. And there's a high chance someone did or will do.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson Ready Player One is basically an alternate present where virtual reality took off and the world's slowly wasting away because people are more interested in playing the game.  To me it's very different because it's handling stuff that's actually happened in reality and nerd/geek culture, both of which don't seem to fall in what Spielberg has done before.  I may be wrong and overlooking something.

Comment: @DForck42 Hmm, from that description I can spot glimpses of *Minority Report* (or Dick in general). But well, in the end he's done so much different stuff, including exploring themes with sociocultural impact or science-fictional extrapolation (e.g. *Schindler's List*, *Jurassic Park*, *Minorty Report*, *Artificial Intelligence*), and recently also delved into animation. As said, I don't say the question makes no sense, but at the moment I can't see *what* it's really that is so unusual about that movie. But feel free to include the things from your comment into the question.

Answer (score 1):

This is a speculative answer as I could not find any source pointing out to "what really excited Spielberg to do this project/movie". I am answering anyways just for that part of OP's question which suggests that it is an odd selection by Spielberg. The answer tries to guess - what could have excited Spielberg about this project :

1. It's a good story

   The book has established itself as a cult favorite. Published in 40 countries, being on New York times best seller list. The ratings for the book are:

   `Amazon.com : 4.6/5
   Barnes & Noble : 4.5/5
   Goodreads : 4.3/5`
2. 80s video game popular culture

   According to deadline.com (unable to post link), the book is loaded with references of popular culture rich in the 1980s video game icons.
3. Spielberg likes different

   May be the story sounds radically different to anything else Steven Spielberg has done yet, but couldn't that be the very reason for him doing this movie.

   When [Adventures of Tintin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Adventures_of_Tintin_%28film%29) was released, I was also surprised when I learned that Spielberg directed an animation movie. So I think he likes to do new things.
4. Good screenwriters

   We should also note that there is a rewrite being done by [Eric Eason](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_Eason) & [Zak Penn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zak_Penn). Zak Penn has scripted movies like X-Men: The Last Stand  and The Avengers. Eric Eason's movie has won Special Jury Award at Sundance.

The movie adaptation script must have excited Spielberg and these all could be the reasons for him deciding to direct this movie.

Comment: I'm not really sure how this answers the question. I believe that the OP is more likely to be looking for information from an interview explaining the situation.

Comment: I could not find Steven Spielberg's official statements about this. I don't think there's an info available on why they did a particular movie for every movie they do. OP finds Spielberg's this particular selection of movie, odd. I tried to reason why it could be normal. although I agree there are no official statements here. But isn't the question itself a little speculative ?

Comment: Not necessarily. It could just be too soon to answer. I'm sure it will be discussed closer to the release date.

Comment: Agreed. Unless we have a "What excited you about this project ?"-question answered by Spielberg, we can't tell for sure. but if it is too soon to answer, isn't it too soon to question too ? :-)

Comment: Interesting points, but could you maybe elaborate a little more how point 2 relates to Spielberg or in which way it could be a reason?